# Distort pattern like contoured fabric

Tags: svg

Can anyone think of a way in SVG to distort a pattern as though it is a piece of fabric with folds and wrinkles?

For instance, if I have a striped beach towel that is laying over an uneven beach, the stripes will not run in straight lines, but will wave and fold and generally distort as they cross the contours of the beach.

I know there are various transformations that can be applied in SVG, but is there any kind of transformation that can apply this sort of distortion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an SVG Filter: feDisplacementMap + feTurbulence. Example:

```
  <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency=".02" numOctaves="4"  result="turb"/>
  <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="turb" scale="0" result="displace" xChannelSelector="B"/>
```

Longer example: http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/nLtla

Comment: I tried your codepen link and I don't see any output. Maybe Firefox doesn't support it?

Comment: Firefox supports feDisplacementMap and feTurbulence. It's the feImage that is an issue, Firefox only supports that for complete images and not for SVG fragments as the example has.